# When filtering data with multiple filters, none of the filters display data until one specific filter is selected

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a few filters for my website. They all filter the data properly but only after all of the filters have been selected.
If I select a city, then it will not display any data, if I just select eye color then it will not work, if I select ethnicity...nothing. I have to select city, eye color, hair color and ethnicity, in order for it to display any data. I want the user to be able to make any selection from each dropdown and it will query and display the data. It updates the page via ajax when the user selects something.
Here is what I have for filters. Sorry for the lengthy post...Got a few filters.

---

Update: I am trying to pull data from 2 tables, ADS table and USERS table. Problem is when I select just the dropdowns that query the ADS table everything works fine, once I add the users table filters into the mix then I need to use a dropdown from each table before the query is displayed.

```
// Set conditions for search 
$whereSQL = $orderSQL = '';
//City selection
if(isset($_POST['city']) || !empty($_POST['city'])){    
    $city = $filter->filter($_POST['city']);
    $whereSQL .= " AND ads.ad_city = :city "; 
}else{
    $city = '';
    $whereSQL .= " AND ads.ad_city != :city "; 
}
//Rate Filter
if(isset($_POST['rateSelect']) || !empty($_POST['rateSelect'])){
    $rate = $_POST['rateSelect'];
    if($rate == "all"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate >= 0 ";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate1"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 0 AND 150 ";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate2"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 151 AND 250 ";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate3"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 251 AND 350 ";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate4"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 351 AND 5000 ";
    }else{
        $whereSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate >= 0 ";
    }
}
//Keywords Filter
if(isset($_POST['keywords']) || !empty($_POST['keywords'])){    
    $keywords = $filter->filter($_POST['keywords']);
    $whereSQL .= "AND ads.ad_content LIKE :keywords "; 
}else{
    $keywords = '';
    $whereSQL .= "AND ads.ad_content LIKE :keywords ";
}
//Ethnicity Filter
//So once these filters from the USERS table are added, the query wont return anything until I select the city and other dropdowns with it.
if(isset($_POST['ethnicity']) || !empty($_POST['ethnicity'])){
    $ethnicity = $filter->filter($_POST['ethnicity']);
    if($ethnicity == "ethnicityall"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.ethnicity != :ethnicity ";
    }else{
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.ethnicity = :ethnicity ";
    }
}else{
    $ethnicity = '';
    $whereSQL .= "AND users.ethnicity != :ethnicity ";
}
//Eye color filter
if(isset($_POST['eyeColorSelect']) || !empty($_POST['eyeColorSelect'])){ 
    $eyeColor = $filter->filter($_POST['eyeColorSelect']);
    if($eyeColor == "eyeColorAll"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.eyeColor != :eyeColor ";
    }else{
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.eyeColor = :eyeColor ";
    } 
}else{
    $eyeColor = '';
    $whereSQL .= "AND users.eyeColor != :eyeColor ";
}
//Hair color filter
if(isset($_POST['hairColor']) || !empty($_POST['hairColor'])){
    $hairColor = $_POST['hairColor'];
    if($hairColor == "hairColorAll"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.hair != :hairColor ";
    }else{
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.hair = :hairColor ";
    }
}else{
    $hairColor = '';
    $whereSQL .= "AND users.hair != :hairColor ";
}
//Height in inches
if(isset($_POST['height']) || !empty($_POST['height'])){
    $height = $filter->filter($_POST['height']);
    if($height == "heightAll"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.height >= 0 ";
    }else if($height == "lessFive"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.height > 1 AND users.height < 152 ";
    }else if($height == "five"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.height > 151 AND users.height < 168 ";
    }else if($height == "fiveSix"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.height > 167 AND users.height < 183 ";
    }else if($height == "sixplus"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.height > 182 ";
    }
}
//Female filter
if(isset($_POST['female']) || !empty($_POST['female'])){
    $female = $_POST['female'];
    if($female == '1'){
        $whereSQL .= "  AND ads.ad_female >= '1'";
    }else if($female = false){
        $whereSQL .= "  AND ads.ad_female == '0'";
    }
}
//male filter
if(isset($_POST['male']) || !empty($_POST['male'])){
    $male = $_POST['male'];
    if($male == '1'){
        $whereSQL .= "  AND ads.ad_male >= '1'";
    }else if($male = false){
        $whereSQL .= "  AND ads.ad_male = '0'";
    }
}
//Sort results
if(!empty($_POST['sortBy']) && (strtoupper($_POST['sortBy']) == 'ASC' || strtoupper($_POST['sortBy']) == 'DESC')){ 
    $sortBy = $filter->filter($_POST['sortBy']);
}else{ 
    $sortBy = 'DESC';
} 
$orderSQL = " ORDER BY ad_date $sortBy "; 
//Query for displaying results
$querySelectCount = "SELECT COUNT(ads.ad_id) as rowNum,
            ads.ad_id,
            ads.ad_title,
            ads.ad_content,
            ads.ad_date,
            ads.ad_user,
            ads.ad_photo,
            ads.ad_photo_thumb,
            ads.ad_age,
            ads.ad_city,
            ads.ad_rate,
            ads.ad_plan,
            ads.ad_approved,
            ads.adminPost,
            ads.ad_female,              
            ads.ad_male,
            users.user_id,
            users.username,
            users.user_picture,
            users.userAge,
            users.height,
            users.hair,
            users.ethnicity,
            users.eyeColor,
            users.type,
            users.industryName              

            FROM
                ads
            INNER JOIN
                users
            ON
                ads.ad_user = users.user_id
            WHERE 
                ads.ad_approved = '0'
            $whereSQL $orderSQL                 
            ";

//Query for pagination results
$querySelect = "SELECT
            ads.ad_id,
            ads.ad_title,
            ads.ad_content,
            ads.ad_date,
            ads.ad_user,
            ads.ad_photo,
            ads.ad_photo_thumb,
            ads.ad_age,
            ads.ad_city,
            ads.ad_rate,
            ads.ad_plan,
            ads.ad_approved,
            ads.adminPost,
            ads.ad_female,
            ads.ad_male,
            users.user_id,
            users.username,
            users.user_picture,
            users.userAge,
            users.height,
            users.hair,
            users.ethnicity,
            users.eyeColor,
            users.type,
            users.industryName              

            FROM
                ads
            INNER JOIN
                users
            ON
                ads.ad_user = users.user_id
            WHERE 
                ads.ad_approved = '0'
            $whereSQL $orderSQL                 
            ";      

// Count all records 
$query = $conn->prepare($querySelectCount); 
$query->bindParam(":city", $city);
$query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%');
$query->bindParam(":hairColor", $hairColor);
$query->bindParam(":ethnicity", $ethnicity);
$query->bindParam(":eyeColor", $eyeColor);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();
$rowCount = $row['rowNum']; 

//var_dump($query);

// Initialize pagination class 
$paginationConfig = array( 
    'baseURL' => $baseURL, 
    'totalRows' => $rowCount, 
    'perPage' => $limit, 
    'currentPage' => $offset, 
    'contentDiv' => 'postContent', 
    'link_func' => 'searchFilter' 
); 
$pagination =  new Pagination($paginationConfig); 

// Fetch records based on the offset and limit 
$querySelect .= " LIMIT $offset,$limit";
$query = $conn->prepare($querySelect);
$query->bindParam(':city', $city);
$query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%');
$query->bindParam(":hairColor", $hairColor);
$query->bindParam(":ethnicity", $ethnicity);
$query->bindParam(":eyeColor", $eyeColor);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Print your queries just before you execute them, cases that work, cases that do not.  Then try to run theses directly on the database (with something like phpmyadmin for example).  Fix the queries as needed.  Worst case, once you have complete queries, show us one that works, one that does not, database tables and we could help then.  A [mcve] would be nice instead of all the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nic3500 it seems that the issue I am having is when I pull data from the USERS table to combine with the ADS table the results do not show unless I select a dropdown from both tables...The dropdowns should query and show data independantly of each other, one not needing the other to display results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the issue, Here is the code I used to correctly query my multiple tables and it works perfectly fine now. The problem was that when sending the values via AJAX to the PHP page, any values that were empty, were either sent as 'null' or empty so I had to run a check for both, as well as change the SELECT query itself.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getData.php',
    data:'page='+page_num+'&city='+city+'&rateSelect='+rateSelect;
    success: function (html) {
        $('#displayPage').html(html);
    }
});
```

Here is some updated code:

```
if(isset($_POST['city']) || !empty($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] !== 'null'){    
    $city = $filter->filter($_POST['city']);
    $adsSQL .= " AND ads.ad_city = :city "; 
}else{
    $city = '';
    $adsSQL .= " AND ads.ad_city != :city "; 
}
//Rate Filter
if(isset($_POST['rateSelect']) || !empty($_POST['rateSelect']) && $_POST['rateSelect'] !== 'null'){
    $rate = $_POST['rateSelect'];
    if($rate == "all"){
       $adsSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate >= 0 ";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate1"){
        $adsSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 0 AND 150 ";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate2"){
        $adsSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 151 AND 250 ";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate3"){
        $adsSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 251 AND 350 ";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate4"){
        $adsSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 351 AND 5000 ";
    }else{
        $adsSQL .= "AND ads.ad_rate >= 0 ";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['eyeColorSelect']) || !empty($_POST['eyeColorSelect'])){ 
    $eyeColor = $filter->filter($_POST['eyeColorSelect']);
    if($eyeColor == "eyeColorAll"){
        $usersSQL.= "AND users.eyeColor != :eyeColor ";
    }else{
        $usersSQL.= "AND users.eyeColor = :eyeColor ";
    } 
}else{
    $eyeColor = '';
    $usersSQL.= "AND users.eyeColor != :eyeColor ";
}
```

I needed to split the query based on each table since I am pulling data from 2 tables. Ads & Users. So I needed to make 2 variables $adSQL and $usersSQL in order to query the 2 tables separately. I got rid of the single query $whereSQL. now when I put the query together it looked like this...

```
$querySelectCount = "SELECT COUNT(ads.ad_id) as rowNum,
            ads.ad_id,
            ads.ad_title,
            ads.ad_content,
            ads.ad_date,
            ads.ad_user,
            ads.ad_photo,
            ads.ad_photo_thumb,
            ads.ad_age,
            ads.ad_city,
            ads.ad_rate,
            ads.ad_plan,
            ads.ad_approved,
            ads.adminPost,
            ads.ad_female,              
            ads.ad_male,
            users.user_id,
            users.username,
            users.user_picture,
            users.userAge,
            users.height,
            users.hair,
            users.ethnicity,
            users.eyeColor,
            users.type,
            users.industryName          

            FROM
                ads
            INNER JOIN
                users
            ON
                ads.ad_user = users.user_id 
            $usersSQL
            WHERE 
                ads.ad_approved = '0'               
            $adsSQL $orderSQL                   
            ";
```

The $usersSQL values came before the WHERE clause and then the $adsSQL values came after. Not sure if it's the most ideal situation but it works perfect in my case.